# Redux Thunk + ReactJS: Action creator being called but dispatch function not being called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm encountering a rather strange problem with my ReactJS x Redux app that I've never seen before and am having a hard time figuring out.

In my ReactJS component I'm wiring up an action creator function that's using `redux-thunk` to make async calls before dispatching to a reducer using the `connect()` function from `react-redux` + the object `mapDispatchToProps` notation. It looks like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    ...state.single_pano
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    loadPano
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PanoView);
```

For the sake of simplicity, let's say the `loadPano` action creator looks something like this:

```
export const loadPano = (id) => {
  console.log('Action creator called.');
  return async (dispatch) => {
    console.log('Dispatch function called.');
    const doc = await db.doc('/path/to/doc/'+id).get();
    dispatch({
      type: 'LOAD_ACTION',
      payload: doc
    });
  }
}
```

*Here's where things get weird:*

In my `componentDidMount()` lifecycle function, I'm making a call to `this.props.loadPano(panoID)` which works exactly as expected (both `console.log()` calls in the action creator are invoked, the `async`/`await` returns and the action is dispatched to the reducer).

Later, I need to call `this.props.loadPano(panoID)` again in the component's `componentWillReceiveProps()` lifecycle function because a URL parameter is changed, and some data needs to be fetched and reloaded. **HOWEVER,** what ends up happening this time is the action creator (`loadPano`) is called, but the `redux-thunk` dispatch function (`return (dispatch) => { ... }`) never gets called. I can tell this is the case because the first `console.log()` is called, but the second one never is never logged to the console.

Other things slighty out of the ordinary that I'm doing that might be related, but so far I've been unable to confirm any of it:

- The `PanoView` component makes use of `shouldComponentUpdate()` lifecycle method to control when the DOM is rendered.
- I'm being a little hacky / not best practice-y using a variable outside of the `PanoView` component's state to store an 3rd party library object that modifies the DOM directly via a DOM `ref`, and can't really be used properly in conjunction with ReactJS. However I believe this to be isolated, and can't see how it would be interfering with Redux / Thunk. Especially because the dispatch function fires correctly the first time.

Relevant dependencies + versions (installed via `yarn`):

```
"firebase": "^5.2.0",
"photo-sphere-viewer": "^3.4.0",
"react": "^16.4.1",
"react-dom": "^16.4.1",
"react-redux": "^5.0.7",
"react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
"redux": "^4.0.0",
"redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
```

**Requested updates:**

My `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecylce function for the `PanoView` component looks as follows:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
  // Pano received
  const oldPanoID = this.props.match.params.panoID;
  const newPanoID = newProps.match.params.panoID;

  if (oldPanoID !== newPanoID) {
    loadPano(newPanoID);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show where you're passing dispatch?

Comment: @Colin Not sure I understand, I'm using the object notation for `mapDispatchToProps` + `react-redux`'s `connect()` to wire up the action creator to the component's props, then in the action creator I'm returning a function (utilizing `redux-thunk`) that calls `dispatch` after the `await` / promise returns. I believe `redux-thunk` is responsible for passing in `dispatch`.

Comment: Could you please share a link to github repo?

Comment: Uh currently it's hosted on a private Bitbucket repo... I've been meaning to move it to GH, but haven't gotten around to it yet.

Comment: @Michal I'll make it a priority tomorrow after I finish work. Should be able to get it up by EOD tomorrow (I'm on Korean Standard Time).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is hard (almost impossible) to guess where the problem is when we don't know anything about your code. How does your `componentWillReceiveProps` look like?

This is a good practice that might cause a confusion:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {
    loadPano
};
```

Redux thunk is essentially a middleware that checks every dispatched action. If the action returns a function, then it calls the function and then it passes `dispatch` and `state` parameters to the returned function and then it also calls this function.

So my guess is:

1. In `componendDidMount` you are calling `this.props.loadPano(id)`
2. In `componentWillReceiveProps` you calling only `loadPano`.

The first one is `store.dispatch(loadPano)` and gets into the reducer. The second one is just `loadPano` and returns a promise. (your action creator)

Comment: Updated the OP. I can't believe I missed this, you were totally correct. Thanks dude, much appreciated. Sometimes the most obvious answers slip right by when you're too close to the action.

Comment: I can't reward the bounty yet, but will as soon as I can. Thanks again.

Comment: Going to be able to release the 2nd beta after this :) I was stuck on this problem all weekend.

Comment: There is a `no-shadow` eslint rule. https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-shadow Unfortunately it wouldn't detect the problem anyway. Maybe `const mapDispatchToProps = { dispatchLoadPano: loadPano };` could help. Good luck with your release. 

Comment: Interesting, I'll defs still check it out, could be useful for future bugs :)